# how to clear server textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox

i am using a client function to clear a textbox (server control runat="server") so when i clear it using jquery it appears empty but when i trace the code and check the textbox.Text control i found the value there and not null so how to clear it also from value property of the textbox control from the client side(i have to clear it from client for user interaction)

**i am using the following to clear it from client side code:**

```
$("#cp1_txtDeathDate").val("");
```

this the code of my control :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDeathDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

in code behind :

```
if (txtDeathDate.Text != "" && DatePattern.IsMatch(txtDeathDate.Text))
{
//do something
}
```

at firebug trace:

```
<input id="cp1_txtDeathDate" type="text" value="26/10/2012" name="ctl00$cp1$txtDeathDate"> // while textbox appeared empty
```

and i am calling the javascript code when the user change value of checkbox by (event click)

```
        function checkDead_click() {


            if ($("#cp1_chDead").prop("checked") == false) {
                $("#cp1_drpDeathReason").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("#cp1_txtDeathDate").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#divDeath input#cp1_radDMR_0').attr('checked', true);
                $("#divDeath input:radio").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#cp1_drpDeathReason").html("");
                $("#cp1_txtDeathDate").val("");
            }
            else {
                $("#cp1_drpDeathReason").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#cp1_txtDeathDate").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#divDeath input:radio").removeAttr('disabled');
            }

        }

$("#cp1_chDead").click(checkDead_click);


protected void Saveform()
    {
        Demographic Demo = new Demographic();


            using (DBEntities DB = new DBEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (hdFormMode.Value == "edit")
                    {
                        string nid = Session["NID"].ToString();
                        Demo = DB.Demographics.SingleOrDefault<Demographic>(d => d.NID == nid);
                    }
                    if (Demo != null || hdFormMode.Value == "new")
                    {

                        Demo.NID = litNID.Text;
                        Demo.BirthDate= txtBirthDate.Text;
                        Demo.FirstName = txtFirstN.Text;
                        Demo.FatherName = txtFatherN.Text;
                        Demo.GrandFName = txtGrandFN.Text;
                        Demo.FamilyName = txtFamilyN.Text;

                        if (txtDeathDate.Text != "" && DatePattern.IsMatch(txtDeathDate.Text))
                        {

                            Demo.DeathDate = txtDeathDate.Text;
                            Demo.RealDeathDate = Convert.ToByte("1");
                         }


                        else
                        {
                            Demo.DeathDate = null;

                        }
                        if (chDead.Checked)
                            Demo.Dead = Convert.ToByte("1");
                        else
                        {
                            Demo.Dead = null;
                            Demo.DeathReason = null;
                            Demo.RealDeathDate = null;
                            Demo.DeathDate = null;

                        }

                        if (hdFormMode.Value == "new")
                        {
                            CreateDemo(Demo);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Demo.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
                            {

                                DB.AttachTo("DBEntities.Dempographics", Demo);
                            }
                            DB.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Demo, EntityState.Modified);
                            DB.SaveChanges();
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Confusing! does your textbox has `runat="server"`?

Comment: May be you should check for string, i.e. textbox.text == "", and not null

Comment: yeah sure do you want me to copy the line ?

Comment: I've given here the server side code. You should check for empty string

Comment: yeah @MurtuzaKabul the same result because i saw the value it self it is not null and not empty string and this is my problem

Comment: Thank you for showing more, but something is still missing (the codebehind, for one). It would seem you are loading something from the database and are overwriting the incoming values.

Comment: what do you mean ? what is missing?

Comment: Like I said, the codebehind is missing, for one.  But I mean that in the broad sense that you're not posting something that is vital. If I knew what that was, I would answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using this to get the client ID of your server control

```
var txtDeathDate = "<%= txtDeathDate.ClientID %>";

//in your actual code should be
$("<%= txtDeathDate.ClientID %>").val("");
```

Also in your code-behind try this

```
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDeathDate.Text) && DatePattern.IsMatch(txtDeathDate.Text))
 {

    Demo.DeathDate = txtDeathDate.Text;
    Demo.RealDeathDate = Convert.ToByte("1");
 }
```

Finally, put a break point and debug your code and see the values of your textbox and variables. Hope this helps!

Comment: the same problem value still there

Comment: show your markup and codebehind if you want help? Your question should be downvoted as you have not provided enough information, but I won't

Comment: really there is nothing special or different to add that is why i didnt add any code i am just clearing a textbox from the client side by this line only!!! and use its value as i said at a code behind as (string x=textbox.Text) then check it if there is text or value so why you want to downvote !!

Comment: because you are making us guessing and trying to imagine what you are trying to do. Seeing the actual code like you have it is better.

Comment: You could have copied `$("#txtbox").val("");` from any tutorial on the web and make us believe is the actual code....

Comment: Oo what is the need to say something not true ??? i need a help so iam honest to say things clearly

Comment: thnx for downvot not fair but it is your opinion and i respect it

Comment: @speciallife I didn't downvote you. If I did I won't mention it. I only warned you because those that would downvote your question had not come and now. If I add mine it would be -3 by now. Your previous question is totally different from what it is now. :(

Comment: yeah i added them to help others to understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

1. textbox.Text from code behind will always have a value (String.Empty), even when empty. It won't be null
2. you cant reference by ID like that because the runat=server will change the value. you'll need to do something like YOURTEXTBOX.ClientID as in $("#<%= YOURTEXTBOX.ClientID %>")

edited to show the actual code of how to ref. via ClientID

Comment: he also said "the value there and not null" so just clarifying

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, replace your code with following...

```
$("#" + "<%=txtbox.CliendID%>").val("");
```

This will be work....

Comment: same problem the value still there :S

Comment: Tell  me which type of textbox you are using i.e either ASp:TextBox or htmp textbox....