# how to clear the textbox text on page load in asp .net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to clear the textbox text after page load when i run my application i will see a login page but the password is displayed in the form of dots and after getting logged out again it appears as dots i should display it empty instead of showing dots and this happens only for password text box i tried in many ways by taking `txtpassword.text="";` in page load also i did `txtpassword.text=string.empty;` but nothing works for me how can i do this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" runat="server"  Width="180px" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: This sounds like it's the browser's autocomplete that's saving login details, not a value coming from your output

Comment: then how can i resolve this issue because the textbox should be empty

Comment: Try adding `autocomplete="off"` as an attribute on the `form` or the `input`, depending on the level you want to disable it

Comment: i had taken in this way <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" runat="server"  Width="180px" Height="20px" TextMode="Password" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox> but yet its not working

Comment: Same behavior in a different browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Comment: You can try '$("#txtpassword").val('');' when document is ready. Or related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329056/how-to-clear-server-textbox-using-jquery

Comment: This Link may be help full [Entity Framework query slow, but same SQL in SqlQuery is fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767803/entity-framework-query-slow-but-same-sql-in-sqlquery-is-fast)

Comment: @abc Sounds like the browser is saving the password. If you did not put code to do that, then try running it in different browsers and see if you get same results.

Comment: then how  to clear that problem  because i need to clear that after getting logged out and before login